# Conditional initialization of a const variable

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, constants

The following base code is part of a quite large procedure:

```
int x = foo();
if (x == 0) x = bar();
```

`x` is not modified anywhere else, so I'd can do:

```
const int x = foo() == 0 ? bar() : foo();
```

But `foo()` is a very expensive and complex function so I can't call it twice due to performance and to the fact that it may generate a race condition and therefore obtain different values (it may involve reading external resources).

I'd like to make code as readable and, if possible, short, as possible. One option is to:

```
const int foo_ = foo(), x = foo_ == 0 ? bar() : foo_;
```

On the other hand, I'd like to avoid that kind of temporal variable mainly because `foo()` may depend on external resources, so using `foo_` as a cached value in the rest of the code is not valid.

I'm posting the solution I'm using right now but I'd like to know if there are better options (none or few code cluttering, no temporal variables in the same scope, readability...). Thanks in advance!

PS: it must follow at least the C++11 standard, since it belongs to a cross-platform project.

I know it may be opinion based, but given the previous statements about simplicity (not cluttering code) and avoiding temporal variables (not for readability but for code safety), I'd like to know options to solve this problem.

Comment: Ternary operators may seem nicer when you write them, but when you come back to the code a month later, they are a nightmare to decipher, especially if you didn't write them yourself. Readability doesn't always go well with short code, and adding comments may be in order

Comment: Please explain why you think "temporal" variables impede "code safety", particularly more so than clever, hard-to-understand "tricks"?

Comment: I agree temporal variables are easier to understand, I'd just want to avoid the chance of using an invalid state due to the existence of such variable (caching the return value of `foo()`). That's why I'm asking the question, is there any chance to have the best of both worlds: readability and safety?

Comment: If your procedure is 'quite large' you should probably first focus on splitting that into smaller procedures (if your goal is maintainability ...)

Comment: @chtz for sure, it is one of the task we are aiming now too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is opinion based question, I would go with:

```
auto get_the_correct_x=[](){
    const auto temp=foo();
    return temp==0?bar():temp;
}
const auto x=get_the_correct_x();
```

A good name instead of `get_the_correct_x` would be even clearer than just trying to play with lambdas without naming.

Comment: If you use that a lot, I'd suggest making it a proper method/function, instead of a lambda-expression, though.

Comment: So far this is the solution I find more useful, may be larger than the inline lambda but generates more readable code, thanks! I'll update the question with the final implementation I used

Answer (score 8):

If you're happy to use [gcc extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html) then you can write:

```
const int x = foo() ?: bar();
```

Comment: Looks great, but unfortunately I must follow the standard since it is a cross-platform code. I'll take it into account for gcc code, thanks! It would be nice to see it in a future standard.

Answer (score 5):

The solution I've found so far is to use a lambda function such as:

```
const int x = [](int n) { return n == 0 ? bar() : n; }(foo());
```

Comment: Yes, but as stated in the question, my concerning with temporal variables is due to the nature of `foo()` more than with the temporal variable itself (if the temporal variable is used its value may be out-of-date). On the other hand, if instead of `int` I'd be using a type with a complex copy-constructor then I'd change it with `const &` instead.

Comment: This is overly complicated and not trivial to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you want the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator), but C++ has none. This is the kind of thing you *might* want to use a second time. So instead of your proposed lambda solution, I opt for a general solution.

For instance

```
#include <functional>

int func_elvis (std::function<int ()> func1, std::function<int ()> func2) {
  int tmp = func1();
  return tmp ? tmp : func2();
}
```

which is then used like

```
const int x = func_elvis(foo, bar);
```

If you prefer to call the functions yourself, you could do

```
#define ELVIS(A, B) func_elvis([](){ return A; }, [](){ return B; })
```

and use it like

```
const int x = ELVIS(foo(), bar());
```

Answer (score 3):

What about a simple:

```
const int temp_foo = foo();
const int x = (temp_foo == 0) ? bar() : temp_foo;
```

Comment: Tahnks, but sorry, as mentioned in the question, I'd like to avoid temporal variables.

Comment: @cbuchart : One would expect it to be optimised away tough, and I find it less confusing then the lambda.

Comment: @cbuchart: _"I'd like to avoid [temporary] variables"_ Why? This is the most obvious, practical and normal solution. Understandable by your compiler and by a person. And it should have absolutely no runtime penalty (why would it? you have the same amount of data and quantity of objects)

Comment: Given the nature of `foo()`, if its result is cached in a temporal variable, and that variable is used later, it may represent an invalid state. I'd like to avoid that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the lambda, and if this situation does not occur many times in your program, you could wrap function `foo()` with a function, let's say `conditionalFoo()`:

```
int conditionalFoo() {
  int result = foo();
  if (result==0)
    result = bar();
  return result;
}
...
const int x = conditionalFoo();
```

Comment: You can use `return bar();` in your function.

Comment: Also, you can pass `foo()` as parameter (making it more similar to the lambda-expression solution proposed by the OP). Then the method should be named `int conditionalBar(int foo)` perhaps.